# Wordpress themes customization

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, widget

I want to add a widget in to my theme and it should display only home page. Also user can add different page URL's to the widget through admin panel and added page should be display in home page. Please help me.....

Answer (score 2):

Just register two separate widget areas. One for the home and one for the test of the site. This way you can add different widgets to each section of your site.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars

Answer (score 0):

JohnP's solution works great if you are comfortable getting into the code. If you would rather work only within the Widget admin page, I would recommend using the Widget Logic plugin which allows you to specify where widgets should and shouldn't be displayed. You can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/. For your setup, simply drag the widget into the widget area and in the widget logic text input place the following:

```
is_home()
```

By doing so, the widget will only show on the home page. Like I said, JohnP's solution will work, but might be more involved than simply doing this.